# Oracle Select unique on multiple column

Tags: oracle, select, unique

How can I achieve this to Select to one row only dynamically since
the objective is to get the uniqueness even on multiple columns

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct
  coalesce(least(ColA, ColB),cola,colb) A1, greatest(ColA, ColB) B1
from T
```

Comment: What if you have a multiple rows and you just want to get the unique values

Comment: This solution will not work if one of the column value is null as least and greatest will give you null if one of the column value is null

Comment: @Tejash that's pretty easy - just add coalesce. I've updated my example

Comment: @DaveesJohnBaclay my query does exactly what you are asking for. It returns unique pairs. Do you need anithing else?

Comment: You need to add coalesce on greatest too.

Comment: @Tejash nope, no need: in case of null - it must be null

Comment: Ok, If `colA,colB = null,5` then your query will display it --> `5, null` -- reversed.

Comment: @Tejash obviously. that's how this algorithm works. As you can see column order is not important for OP, he needs unique pairs, so one scan is optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use `UNION`

```
select colA from your_table
union
select colB from your_table;
```

**Update**:

If you want to find the duplicate then use the `EXISTS` as follows:

```
SELECT COLA, COLB FROM YOUR_TABLE T1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM YOUR_tABLE T2
                       WHERE T2.COLA = T1.COLB OR T2.COLB = T1.COLA)
```

Comment: I need to return two columns, just to treat that the 2 rows are equal

Comment: Updated answer to give duplicate records

Comment: (T2.COLA = T1.COLA OR T2.COLA = T1.COLB) ? "OR"? You solution for duplicates considers (123,456) and (123,999) as duplicates

Comment: Still wrong: check again, now with (123,456) and (999,123)

Comment: it should be simple SELECT COLA, COLB FROM YOUR_TABLE T1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM YOUR_tABLE T2 WHERE T2.COLA = T1.COLB 
 and T2.COLB = T1.COLA)

Comment: My understanding is that -- 1,2 and 2,3 are also duplicate. am I misunderstood?

Comment: Example that supports nulls: https://gist.github.com/xtender/6a0bef926fd84688e803a99ea72cd864

Comment: OP asks for uniqueness even on multiple columns, whole row, not just one column in row, in this case - pairs

Comment: Ok, Then it was easy. I received 2-3 such questions in the past 24 hours so was in that dilemma. By the way, Updated the answer now. Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand words: *objective is to get the uniqueness even on multiple columns*, number of columns may vary, table can contain 2, 3 or more columns.

In this case you have several options, for example you can unpivot values, sort, pivot and take unique values. The exact code depends on Oracle version.
Second option is `listagg()`, but it has limited length and you should use separators not appearing in values.

Another option is to compare data as collections. Here I used `dbms_debug_vc2coll` which is simple table of varchars. `Multiset except` does main job:

```
with t as (select rownum rn, col1, col2, col3,
                  sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll(col1, col2, col3) as coll 
             from test )
select col1, col2, col3 from t a
  where not exists (
    select 1 from t b where b.rn < a.rn and a.coll multiset except b.coll is empty )
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9b64f049f10834c5d19f5ac72fc49121) with 3-column table, nulls and different test cases